# Custom target image not detecting using Vuforia SDK in Android

Tags: vuforia

I am able to track the stone and chips images but when I created my own target image using Target manager I was not able to track the image. I imported the database. It has 5 star rating. But the image is not getting identified. I am new to this.

What else do I need to do to track a custom target image?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone facing the same problem in 2021.
To solve this, you need to generate a license key and add it in the Vuforia Configuration Tab. This worked for me at least...

Answer (score 1):

To import your Image Target you need to remember about few things:

1. Proper Vuforia ARCamera Configuration. You can find example [here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Compiling-a-Simple-Unity-Project).
2. Adding Image Target prefab to Unity scene and selecting db and target. [Here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Image-Targets-in-Unity) you can find short video how to do it.
3. Look on Unity console. It can give you set of useful information.
4. Remember about application key.

Add some cubes under the Image Target prefab to make sure that it was detected.

Comment: Thanks for answering Adam ,but i tried every thing what u have mentioned here and i also also followed steps mention in this link "https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-to-replace-the-dataset-in-the-Android-Image-Targets-sample",but still not able to recoganised my target image ...

Comment: Paste a link to the screenshots of: ARCamera Config, Image Target, your Unity Project hierarchy. Run project in Playmode in Unity and make a ss of  Unity Console as well. Make screenshots of everything and give me a link there. I will try to find an issue.

Comment: +1. This answer helped me realize I forgot to add my Vuforia app license key to the new project I was working in.

Answer (score 1):

In the VuforiaConfiguration -> Databases, make sure you have checked the checkboxes next to your custom targets, in my case "Load MyTargets Database" and the child "Activate".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have performed the following steps precisely:

1. Import Vuforia SDK.
2. Import your downloaded target database unity package.
3. Drag an **ARCamera** prefab into your scene, select it and in the inspector panel
   add your license key.
4. Drag an **ImageTarget** prefab into your scene, select it and in the
   inspector panel look for **ImageTargetBehaviour** script. Make sure
   you select,

   - **Type = Predefined**
   - **Data Set = (Your Imported DataSet)**
   - **Image Target = (The image target you want from your DataSet)**
5. Drag a cube or whatever object you want to augment in your scene.
   Make sure to **make this object a child object of the Image Target. This is a must**.
6. Again select the **ARCamera** object and under
   **DatabaseLoadBehaviour** script make sure to check **Load Data Set** and **Activiate** checkboxes.
7. Build and Run.

And hopefully this should work just fine, as it did for me. Thanks!